# Staying in Windows, how can I know my Ubuntu version?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, versions

I installed simultaneously Win7 in a machine with Ubuntu. Now i want to enter to Ubuntu but it always gets me to the Windows side.

I know I have to use a bootable USB but I don't know the version of ubuntu to use the correct ISO image.

Any ideas?

Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Windows 7 after you installed Ubuntu, you probably did 1 of 2 things:

You either installed Windows 7 over Ubuntu and deleted everything, or when you installed Windows 7 in a separate partition you overwrote the Grub bootloader. If the first was the case, then you'll need to reinstall Ubuntu and Windows 7 on separate partitions. If the latter, you'll probably want to see [this](https://superuser.com/a/134808) answer. Summarily, you can just boot into your Windows environment, go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/) and get the latest version of Grub4dos, and install it on the hard drive that you installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Boot-Repair --> [Create Boot-Info Summary](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) .
2. Look at the log created. This will indicates which Ubuntu version you have on your disk.